# How to run SonarQubeScanner from .gitlab-ci.yml for C# projects?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, sonarqube, gitlab-ci

How can I integrate sonarqube for c# projects (specifically for Xamarin forms) in .gitlab-ci.yml file. (Using docker image if possible ) Thank you.